# how to show data based on date slicer but from 2 dates columns

Tags: powerbi

Currently, I have a report that displays a series of data that I can filter on the basis of a "date slicer (type 'between')". This slicer works with as specifi column "i_date" because a date table (m_date[date]) is used for the slicer and the "i_date" (from another table "interv") is linked together (1:n relathions).

In this other table there is another date type column with the last modification date of the row (interv[modified]).

Now, when a period is selected with the date slicer,  I'd like to show the data where interv[i_date] OR interv[modified] are inside the selected period.

How can I do that  ?

Using a new column with the newest date between interv[i_date] OR interv[modified] is not a solution, because in this case if a row is modified after the period, it will not be shown.  (because interv[i_date]  <  interv[modified])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved with a second slicer simply